# Memory management mechanism in RxSwift

Tags: memory-management, subscription, disposable

I've been studying Rxswift for a while, so far I'm able to apply Rxswift to my projects. However I still don't understand how RxSwift manages the memory resources, especially the *Disposable* objects. For example:

```
func foo() {
            let s = Observable.of(1).subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
            s.disposed(by: _disposeBag)
        }
```

In the method above, s is a *Disposable* object, and as I understand, the object persists until it is disposed (by either the *_disposeBag* being released or by calling *.dispose()* directly on s), meaning that *something* is holding a strong reference to s, but I don't know what that *something* is.

I've been looking for documentations on this matter, but no hope so far. Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2):

The DisposeBag holds a strong reference to the disposable when you call disposed(by:), and assuming the DisposeBag is retained by a UIViewController for example, when the UIViewController is deallocated the DisposeBag will be deallocated and in its deinit() function it call dispose() of every disposable it retains.

HTH

Comment: This sounds reasonable, can you kindly send me the official docs regarding your answer?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#disposing, "When a DisposeBag is deallocated, it will call dispose on each of the added disposables."